# Detecting page filename using php?

Tags: php, detect

I am making a menu on a Wordpress template and need the menu to detect the current page and highlight it. So for instance, my menu is:

```
<li><a href="index.php" class="current">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
```

So if the user is on the About page, I want that one to have the "class=current". How is this possible? I hear using the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is possible? Please appreciate that I have zero knowledge in php coding, so kindly make any replies detailed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use a little snippet like this one. If your visitor is on `about.php`, `$basename` will equal `about`.

```
$basename = substr(strtolower(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])),0,strlen(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))-4);
```

The HTML Would be something like this.

```
<li><a href="index.php"<?php if ($basename == 'index') echo ' class="current"'; ?>>Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php"<?php if ($basename == 'about') echo ' class="current"'; ?>>About</a></li>
```

Comment: Excellent, could you please show me how I would use the $basename in the html code? As I mentioned, my knowledge with PHP and how to use it is literally zero.

Comment: Yes it did. You had one to many quotationmarks there, but this worked fine :)

Comment: Good Catch! Updated. +1 on the question for that!

Comment: Would using SCRIPT_NAME instead of PHP_SELF be better, as it only returns the file name?

Answer (score 1):

```
$myPage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
<li><a href="index.php" class="<?echo ($myPage == 'index.php'?'current':'')?>">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php" class="<?echo ($myPage == 'about.php'?'current':'')?>">About</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll can use something of the form:

```
<li><a href="index.php"<?php if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == 'index.php') echo ' class="current"'); ?>>Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php"<?php if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == 'about.php') echo ' class="current"'); ?>>About</a></li>
```

That said, you'll probably want to incorporate the above into a function.

Irrespective, I'd recommend reading the PHP manual's [getting started section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php) before you go any further - it'll be time wisely spent.

Comment: Out of interest, why would I need to incorporate it into a function if your example works?

Comment: Also will 'PHP_SELF'] == 'index.php' detect a URL that is index.php?random...?

Comment: @alexander 1. You don't need to include it in a function, it's just neater and provides a central location for any future improvements. 2. PHP_SELF is the filename of the currently executing script, so it won't include any query string args.